# solution of pendulum equation

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, differential-equations

I have the pendulum expression

$$\ddot{\theta}+\omega_{o}^{2}\sin(\theta)=0,$$

where I used a Taylor expansion for the sine term:

$$\ddot{\theta}+\omega_{o}^{2}\left(\theta-\frac{1}{6}\theta^3\right)=0$$

How do I solve this differential equation for a simple pendulum?

Comment: Um, do you mean $\sin\theta\approx\theta-\frac{1}{3!}\theta^3$? $\sin\theta=\theta-\frac{1}{3!}\sin^{3}\theta$ has only one solution over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Actually i am looking for the solution of the differential equation

Comment: sorry that i did some mistakes earlier

Comment: I think you can solve that non-linear ODE through elliptic functions/integrals.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, for a simple pendulum, you approximate the term $\sin(\theta)$ by just the linear term $\theta$. In this case it is still valid for small angles (for $\theta\lesssim 10^\circ$, there error is still less than 1%) and fairly valid for larger angles. This approximation is therefore accurate enough for most applications.

If you include a $\theta^3$ term, it is still an approximation, but your equations become much more complicated. Maple gives me some Jacobi elliptic functions. Only go down this road if you absolutely need this (which I doubt in your case). Otherewise, stick to the first order approximation. (Or second order if you like, since there is no $\theta^2$ term)

Comment: Where do you get 10 degrees from?

Comment: That's rather arbitrary, depends on the accuracy you are looking for: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+sin%28x%2F180*pi%29-%28x*pi%2F180%29%2C+x%3D-20..20

Comment: @Mew Thanks for your comment, I updated the answer a bit.